# SQL Server linked to AccessDB Update statement doesn't work in some scenarios

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server 2014 Express server linked to an Access DB. I am able to SELECT and view data in the access db without issue. However, when I run update statements they don't always work. The linked server name is PINKSHEET.

The update query below fails.

```
UPDATE PINKSHEET...[I Warehouse]
SET [Warehouse Name] = 'Test'
WHERE ([Warehouse ID #] = 3)
```

with the message

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'I'.

followed by the message

> Cannot execute the query "UPDATE I Warehouse set `Warehouse Name` = 'Test'  WHERE `Warehouse ID #`= ? " against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "PINKSHEET".

If I rewrite the above query as noted below it works without issue.

```
UPDATE PINKSHEET...[I Warehouse]
SET [Warehouse Name] = 'Test'
WHERE [Warehouse ID #] IN (SELECT [Warehouse ID #] FROM PINKSHEET...[I 
Warehouse] WHERE [Warehouse ID #] = 3)
```

I cannot figure out why the simpler structure throws the error.